Ошибка в коде disnake
passwords = open("codes.txt", "r")
password1 = passwords.readline()
passwords.close()

import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands


users = [639713374992597024, 653252704117981185, 1013463398073257996, 686994022971342898]

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", help_command=None, intents=disnake.Intents.all(),
                   test_guilds=[1122189705459531786])


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot {bot.user} is ready to work!")





@bot.slash_command()
async def codes(inter, password):
    print(password + password1)
    if str(password) == str(password1):
        for ID in users:
            user = bot.get_user(ID)
            await member.send("проль: тест")
            await inter.send("Код отправлен: " + user.name)
    else:
        await inter.send("Пароль неверный.")

bot.run("секрет")


Ошибка:
Ignoring exception in slash command 'codes':
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\slash_core.py", line 728, in invoke
await call_param_func(self.callback, inter, self.cog, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\params.py", line 1083, in call_param_func
return await maybe_coroutine(safe_call, function, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\disnake\utils.py", line 567, in maybe_coroutine
return await value
^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\crach-bot.py", line 29, in codes
await member.send("проль: тест")
^^^^^^
NameError: name 'member' is not defined
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\interaction_bot_base.py", line 1378, in process_application_commands
await app_command.invoke(interaction)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\slash_core.py", line 737, in invoke
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'member' is not defined

Ignoring exception in slash command 'codes':
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\slash_core.py", line 728, in invoke
await call_param_func(self.callback, inter, self.cog, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\params.py", line 1083, in call_param_func
return await maybe_coroutine(safe_call, function, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\disnake\utils.py", line 567, in maybe_coroutine
return await value
^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\crach-bot.py", line 70, in codes
await user.send("пароль: тест")
^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\interaction_bot_base.py", line 1378, in process_application_commands
await app_command.invoke(interaction)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\slash_core.py", line 737, in invoke
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
Теперь пишет эту ошибку

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

вы хоть напишите, что за ошибка.

В коде ошибки же ясно сказано: NameError: name 'member' is not defined. Значит переменной member нету и нужно ее создать, либо использовать существующий вариант.
Попробуйте этот код:
@bot.slash_command()
async def codes(inter, password):
    print(password + password1)
    if str(password) == str(password1):
        for ID in users:
            user = bot.get_user(ID)
            await user.send("пароль: тест")
            await inter.send("Код отправлен: " + user.name)
    else:
        await inter.send("Пароль неверный.")

